# Column values Coming as Exponent in Excel from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I was working on SQL Server 14, one of the column had relatively huge value. When I copied the data from SQL Server and posted it in Excel, the value got changed to Exponent power. I don't want that, I want the original value as it is in excel.
What needs to be done in the query?
P.S: The column is of type Varchar and I cannot change the structure of the table.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just format the `excel` cell to text:

[image]

[image]

You can see on the picture above same value pasted in cell formatted as `general` and in a cell formatted as `Text`.

Comment: @Sarthak_D You can mark it as answered using the check.